# catkin / setup.py installation into devel space not working

Tags: ros, python, setup.py, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I can't figure out how to correctly package a Python module so it shows up in my devel space after "catkin_make".  I've tried every combination of setup.py and CMakeLists.txt that I can think of.

Let's say I have a ROS package called "my_package", and I'd like to have a Python module defined by "my_package.py" containing a function called "def myfunc()", so that from a different package, I could do "import my_package; my_package.myfunc()".  After catkin_make, I expect things to be installed like this: devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package.py.  How do I write a CMakeLists.txt and setup.py for this package?

If this configuration is impossible, how do you recommend I structure a simple ROS package providing Python modules?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I'm using Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50661/catkin-/-setup.py-installation-into-devel-space-not-working/) by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 462 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial on that here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile
(click catkin) Section 2.2

Also some more info here:
http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html

Note that catkin does not put your my_package.py in the devel space, it uses the one in your source space via some python voodoo, so in your devel space you will just get some **init**.py.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-01-09**:
Thanks; this answered my question.  It would be helpful if the **init**.py voodoo were documented somewhere (at least for people like me who are curious how the devel space works).